# R - combine data frames of different lengths after loop

Tags: r, loops, merge, dataframe

I am looping through a series of 15 files. My loop looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(mod.f)) {
    do some stuff
    dataframe `df` is produced
}
```

Each iteration of the loop will yield a data frame with two columns - date and some value, just like the example below:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(-43829, -43798, -43770, -43739, 
-43709, -43678, -43648, -43617, -43586, -43556, -43525, -43495, 
-43464, -43433, -43405, -43374, -43344, -43313, -43283, -43252
), class = "Date"), inmcm4 = c(71.4782417258324, 68.5037706662898, 
64.0571482842429, 62.8708849771957, 66.3121740437669, 62.7535770507166, 
62.2819567665719, 62.3014754255822, 58.6247123853888, 58.4425949480101, 
61.3534245382973, 68.2531958750396, 70.4892992599108, 70.1840748468477, 
64.6298343911645, 66.5280510648649, 65.2767506692563, 62.8944646174169, 
60.4309882672837, 58.7368776782633)), .Names = c("date", "inmcm4"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem here is that not all the data frames have the same length. The lengths of each data frame are the following:

```
1872 
1740 
1872 
1932 
1872 
1752 
1752 
1872 
1872 
672 
1872 
1872 
1956 
1956 
1872
```

As a result, not all dates (e.g. df$date) will be the same.

What I wish to do is to combine all data frames in one single data frame by the end of the loop. This final data frame should have a `date` column and the remaining columns would be the values of each iteration, assigning NA's to the dates that don't overlap.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='date', all=TRUE), lst)
```

where `lst` is the list of data.frames

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df2 <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),8, replace=FALSE),]
row.names(df2) <- NULL
lst <- list(df, df2)
```

Comment: the problem is that each loop generates one data frame (please see the edited information on the OP). Therefore, I don't have a list of data.frames.

Comment: @thiagoveloso  You can divert the output of each iteration to a `lst` and then use the code.  It may be easier to work with `lapply`.  Otherwise, define a list at the beginning.  `lst <- vector('list',  4); for (i in 1:length(mod.f)) { lst[[i]] <- do some stuff}`  Change 4 to the number of iterations

Comment: It worked! I just used `lst <- vector('list', length(mod.f)); for (i in 1:length(mod.f)) { lst[[i]] <- df}`. The final result is pretty elegant. Thanks for such a simple and efficient answer! I wonder when I will **really** learn R. :(

Comment: @thiagoveloso  Thank you for the feedback.  Regarding your final comment, you could spend some 10-15 mins everyday to solve problems using R, it will be easier after a certain period of time.